# Is it possible to send HEAD request with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to send HEAD request to server to get a file length from Content-Length header, but I always get 'Not Acceptable' in response when I'm using RestSharp. Id I create request with simple .NET WebRequest it work good.

I tried to clear all header and other stuff from request and client, but had no success

Is it possible to do this request with RestSharp and how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with

```
restRequest.Parameters.Clear();
restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var request = new RestRequest("/resource", Method.HEAD);
```

Comment: Already tried, it does not work. I solved it by myself, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following approach if someone is interested:

```
using RestSharp;

 var client = new RestClient("/resource");
 var request = new RestRequest();

 var response = client.Head(request);
```