# .NET - Checking if a URL is pointing at a valid resource

Tags: .net, rest

I need to check if a given URL is pointing at a valid resource. The URL, when valid, will be pointing at our API and would be something like this: "https://api.mycompany.com/api/rest/download?token=GUIDgoesHere"

Normally those URLs are used to download files that have been uploaded via the API but I *DO NOT* want to download the actual file, just verify that that URL is pointing to a valid resource/file.

I figured that this would be possible by sending some sort of REST request to that URL and checking for a StatusCode of 200, or something like that.

Is this possible doing something like that? Or am I way off? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Something like this (I also have the RestSharp library):

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;

try
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Comment: How do you define "valid resource"? What if I write a server that randomly fails or succeeds a URL?

Comment: Yes; your only option is to send a normal HTTP request, see what happens, and hope it's consistent.  But note that it may depend on headers.

Comment: Seems to me the best method would be to create a parameter to handle that.  Something like :  "https://api.mycompany.com/api/rest/download?token=GUIDgoesHere&validateOnly=true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good opportunity to use a HEAD request instead of GET.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Since you mention using RestSharp: [Is it possible to send HEAD request with RestSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668988/is-it-possible-to-send-head-request-with-restsharp)

Comment: Ah, I did not know of such a thing until I read your reply this morning. It was exactly what I was hoping existed or I could do in this case. From the results of some testing, another department will have to change the API to explicitly allow the HEAD request but I think it should be good once they do. Thank you very much for your response, and I learned something new today! Haha.